# Iterator loop in C++

Tags: c++

I've been googling for this for so long but I couldn't get the answer. The most of sample that I found are based on iterating with vector, map and etc..

I have the code below.

```
multimap<int, int>::iterator it = myMuliMap.find(1);
```

Let's say I have three pairs that has key "1". I like to get those three pair from for loop.. I think that I can't use for(multimap::iterator anotherItr=myMuliMap.begin()..

The following code is in C#.. I like to get C++ version.. Thanks.

```
foreach(var mypair in it){
  Console.WriteLine(mypair.Key);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you're looking for is equal_range.  This returns an iterator to all pairs in the map which match the specified key

```
auto range = myMultiMap.equal_range(1);
for ( auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it) {
 ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Version without auto

```
pair<multimap<int,int>::const_iterator,multimap<int,int>::const_iterator>> it = myMultiMap.equal_range(1);
for ( multimap<int,int>::const_iterator it = range.first;
      it != range.second;
      ++it) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: it might be a bit early to use `auto` without mentioning that it's not strictly speaking part of C++ yet. Give it another year or so. ;)

Comment: this will give an error as it will be std::pair<std::multimap<int,int>::iterator, std::multimap<int,int>::iterator> and not just a single iterator.

Comment: I already have multimap<int, int>::iterator it = myMuliMap.find(1); so I'm not so sure that I need equal_range(); Should I use equal_range instead of find()?

Comment: @Michael, added a non-auto version

Comment: @jalf, but `auto` is so much more elegant :)

Comment: @diverscuba23, yes it gives back a pair but I iterate agaist the `first` member.

Comment: If you're providing the non-`auto` version for C++03 compatibility reasons then you should also put a space between the two closing `>` of the type `pair<multimap<int, int>::const_iterator, multimap<int, int>::const_iterator> >` as without it is not valid in C++03.

Comment: @JaredPar: yep, I agree, auto looks much nicer. I'm just saying it might confuse someone who only knows C++03 (and may or may not know the *old* meaning of the keyword)

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::equal_range()`:

```
int tolookfor = 1;
typedef multimap<int, int>::iterator iterator;
std::pair<iterator, iterator> p = 
    std::equal_range(myMuliMap.begin(), myMuliMap.end(), tolookfor);

for (iterator it = p.first; it != p.second ++it)
    std::cout << (*it).second << std::endl;
```

the multi_map's member function `equal_range` works similarily:

```
std::pair<iterator, iterator> p = 
    myMuliMap.equal_range(tolookfor);
```

Comment: if your looking for a value within the whole multimap, there is a version of equal_range that only takes the key as an argument.

Comment: pair<iterator, iterator> is giving me problem.

Comment: What problems do you get? Is `myMultiMap` a const instance? If so, you need to use `typedef multimap<int, int>::const_iterator iterator;`.

Answer (score 1):

This will print out only the values found by

```
std::pair<std::multimap<int, int>::iterator, std::multimap<int, int>::iterator> result;
result = myMultimap.equal_range(1);

for(std::multimap<int,int>::iterator it = result.first; it != result.second; it++)
{
    std::cout << it->first << " = " << it->second << std:: endl;
}
```

Comment: What are the differences between find and equal_range()?

Comment: find will return an iterator to the first element that matches, or to a sentinal value that represents not found. equal_range will return a pair that represents the first element that is equal to the value you are looking for, and one past the last element that is equal to the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following loop.

```
for (std::multimap<int, int>::iterator i  = myMultiMap.lower_bound(1);
                                       i != myMultiMap.upper_bound(1);
                                     ++i)
{
    std::cout << i->first << " => " << i->second << '\n';
}
```

This is valid in the current version of C++.

Comment: You mean, I don't need to use Find() ??

Comment: @Michael Sync: You don't need to, no. `find` and `lower_bound` do the same job, the only difference is what they return if there's no matching element. `find(x)` returns `end()` whereas `lower_bound(x)` points at first element in the sequence that sorts after the element that you were searching for, which is the same as `upper_bound(x)`.